# pyenchant error "DictNotFoundError: Dictionary for language 'en_US' could not be found"

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, aspell, pyenchant, enchant

I am running Python 3.6 in Spyder/Anaconda, I am trying to use enchant. I installed pyenchant using

```
pip install pyenchant
```

I also installed aspell using

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-en
```

I am executing in Python:

```
import enchant

print("The dict is", enchant.list_languages())

slownik = enchant.Dict("en_US")
```

I keep getting an error:

> File
>   "/home/grzegorz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enchant/**init**.py",
>   line 562, in **init**
>       _EnchantObject.**init**(self)
>
> File
>   "/home/grzegorz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enchant/**init**.py",
>   line 168, in **init**
>       self._init_this()
>
> File
>   "/home/grzegorz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enchant/**init**.py",
>   line 569, in _init_this
>       this = self._broker._request_dict_data(self.tag)
>
> File
>   "/home/grzegorz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enchant/**init**.py",
>   line 310, in _request_dict_data
>       self._raise_error(eStr % (tag,),DictNotFoundError)
>
> File
>   "/home/grzegorz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enchant/**init**.py",
>   line 258, in _raise_error
>       raise eclass(default)
>
> DictNotFoundError: Dictionary for language 'en_US' could not be found

And the printout is:

> The dict is []

so no dictionaries are being loaded. It seems that enchant does not know where the aspell dictionaries are located.

I tried numerous variations of

```
enchant.set_param("enchant.aspell.dictionary.path","/aspell") enchant.set_param("enchant.myspell.dictionary.path","/usr/bin/aspell")
```

What may be relevant: this simple code worked before I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 (from 17.4), so I somehow got enchant to work then, but it was long ago and I cannot recreate what I did differently when installing enchant back then. I have also updated Spyder to the latest version, one of those operations clearly caused the code to break. I was updating Spyder in the past and it did not cause any problems, so I am suspecting that during the system update something important got deleted/moved.
I found answers for people with similar issues on MacOS, but the answers I found do not work on Ubuntu.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any solutions yet for Python3.6 @Grzegorz Swirszcz ?

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution - downgrade to Python 3.5. It seems that pyenchant 1.6.11 is not Python 3.6 compatible and that it only tries to import Hspel (Hebrew) library when used with Python 3.6. I would love to be able to use the newest Python, so the issue is not resolved, but that is the best (and only) solution so far.